# How to stop 'Enter Parameter Value' after I refresh/close my form in MS Access?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm setting up a new tooling managment database using the form in MS Access, there is one command key in my form (Asset List) to open another form (Asset Details) for viewing and editting data, whenever i close the Asset Details form, I was prompted to enter parameter value for ID where i don't even have the object or field named ID. It happened when i edit anything in the Asset List too.

Here's the code that I used for opening the Asset Details Form.

```
Event="OnClick">
<Statements>
<Action Name="OpenForm">
<Argument Name="FormName">Asset Details</Argument>
<Argument Name="WhereCondition">1=0</Argument>
<Argument Name="WindowMode">Dialog</Argument></Action><Action Name="OnError"/>
<Action Name="Requery"/>
<Action Name="SearchForRecord">
<Argument Name="WhereCondition">="[Tooling No]=" &amp; Nz(DMax("[Tooling No]",[Form].[RecordSource]),0)</Argument>
</Action>
</Statements>
</UserInterfaceMacro>
</UserInterfaceMacros>
```

I expect that the asset details will auto update or refresh after I close the Asset Details form without prompting 'Enter Parameter Value'.

Comment: Is this an Access embedded macro? Why don't you use form/subform arrangement for Asset and AssetDetails?

Comment: @June7 Yes, it's Access embedded macro. My Asset List form is using form/subform where the data source is my asset table, do you mean that include my asset details in my asset list also?

Comment: I've never seen macro code shown with HTML-like tags. Asset form is a subform? Why is it not main form then AssetDetails a subform on Asset form? I don't use macros, only VBA. If I did want to open a form to a specific record, I would use something like: `DoCmd.OpenForm "Asset Details", , , "AssetID=" & Me.tbxAsset, , acDialog`

Comment: @june7 I'd convert the macro to vba that's why shown in this way i think. i can open my asset details subform from my asset main form but whenever i close the asset details form, it prompt me to enter parameter value for ID, is there anyway to check where the ID object is?

Comment: Does the form RecordSource have dynamic parameter? Your DMax() is not used correctly. The domain can't be a form, must be a table or query.

Comment: The RecordSource for my Asset is query.

Comment: Doesn't matter what the form RecordSource is. Domain aggregate function must reference a table or query object, not a form RecordSource.

Comment: @june7 i'd changed the domain to tblAsset, but Access still prompt me to enter parameter value for ID

Comment: Well, it's not referenced in the code you posted so can't help with that. You will have to track it down. I did suggest you look in RecordSource. There are third-party add-ins that can do searches through object properties. http://www.utteraccess.com/wiki/index.php?title=VTools_AddIns&diff=3690&oldid=3680

Comment: @june7 Alright, thank you!